# Issue in writing a SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff, join

I have a MySQL table called `Hotel`. in that i have the following fields `ID`,`hotelName`,`Address`,`YearOfEstablishment`.

The `YearOfEstablishment` is type `Date` and it'll store a date as `2010-12-26`. What i need to do is to find the difference between the dates, and the SQL for that is as follows;

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2011-08-08','2010-07-26');
```

The answer for the above query will be given in days, like for example the difference between the 2 dates might be `120` days, I need to show this in `Years`. Like to divide the value `120` by `365` and give the number of years. How do i write the SQL statement for this?

2.) Now i need to write another SQL, that would show all the `Hotel` table columns and the `Year difference values` (that is explained above). How do i write the SQL for this?

(I am using MySQL)

Comment: Differences require two values... you've only got YearOfEstablishment. Where does the other value come from? Are you comparing all the hotels together to find which one is oldest? Comparing to today's date to get the age of the hotel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `SELECT DATEDIFF('2011-08-08','2010-07-26') / 365;`
2. `SELECT ID,hotelName,Address,YearOfEstablishment, DATEDIFF(YearOfEstablishment,'2010-07-26') / 365 AS years FROM Hotel;`

However, be sure to know that an [*average* year has 365.2425 days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year#Calendar_year).

And if your reference datetime is now, simply use `NOW()`: `SELECT DATEDIFF('2011-08-08',NOW()) / 365;`.

Comment: What is the complete SQL for your 2nd answer. there should be a `From Table_Name` as well, How should i include that ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a query like this:

```
SELECT ID, hotelName, Address, YearOfEstablishment, (DATEDIFF(YearOfEstablishment, '2010-07-26')/365) AS differenceInYears
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`SELECT MOD (DATEDIFF('2011-08-08','2010-07-26'), 365) ;`

Comment: Won't work. datediff returns number of days, which is a simple integer. There's no 'year' to extract since it's note a date/datetime value.